# Powershell -AccessRights fullaccess script doesn't work with more than one to one in csv

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I will add  `-AccessRights fullaccess` but  it only work when csv file looks like

```
"Name","GrantSendonBehalfTo"
"OJE01","ore.se/lk/forv/socf/NYMXX04"
```

When its more than one to one the csvfile dont work How to fix that ????

```
"Name","GrantSendonBehalfTo"
"KEU01","ore.se/lk/forv/socf/BEAXX37;ore.se/lk/forv/socf/ERC01"
```

Step One

```
Get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Identity * 
    | where {$_.GrantSendOnBehalfTo}
    | Select-Object name,@{Name='GrantSendonBehalfTo';Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.GrantSendonBehalfTo))}} 
    | Export-Csv c:\Grant.txt -Delimiter ','
```

Step TWO

```
Import-Csv C:\Grant.txt 
    | foreach{Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Name -User $_.GrantSendonBehalfTo -AccessRights fullaccess}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You joined the grantees with a semicolon, so naturally you need to split those joint grantees before you can (re-)assign access:

```
Import-Csv C:\Grant.txt | % {
  $name = $_.Name
  $_.GrantSendonBehalfTo -split ';' | % {
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $name -User $_ -AccessRights fullaccess
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I got an error anyway
Cannot procces argument transforamtion on parameter 'User'. Cannot convert value "@{Name=BOSS-Calender; GrantSendonBehalfTo=sudoko.ne/at/forv/MEI01;sudoko.net/at/buf/WAI05